# HTTPS broken (on meta)

Tags: support

Trying to navigate too https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/ for me ends up with my browser (Firefox) throwing a site certificate error. Adding a exception then results in a 403 error page:

> [image]

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ works but has the usual 'some stuff not secure issue' (so images etc). Normal https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/ works as well.

N.B. I am using the HTTPS Everywhere addon, so it tries to use HTTPS when possible.

Comment: We don't officially support HTTPS yet, particularly not on child meta sites. See this blog post on the reasons: http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/