# How to deal with images hosted on i.stack.imgur.com, and mixed content warnings?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to raise this, nor if anyone else sees it as an issue which needs to be dealt with.
By default, images uploaded through the Question/Answer editor are hosted at https://i.stack.imgur.com, this leads to mixed content warnings when browsing the site over https.

Examples:

- [What's the use of a decoupling capacitor near a reservoir capacitor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59325/)
- [How do I know where I need decoupling capacitors?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17126/)
- [Will a 0402 0.01 µF ceramic capacitor next to a 0402 0.1 µF ceramic capacitor have any power decoupling benefits?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25280/)

I am quite happy to edit the offending URL's to be https, instead of http, as I come across them, but I do not know if this would at all be appreciated by those looking after the review queues, nor if there is a reason I do not know of for them to be inserted as http by default.

My question is two-fold, is it possible to change the image upload to default to https? If not, would it be acceptable to edit the affected posts to change the URL's to https?

**Please note:** I am aware that browsers handle mixed content in different manners, and depending on the users settings, or browser, there might not be any sign which points out that they are viewing a page with mixed content.

**Why bother?** Spurious warnings regarding TLS is an issue which browser implementers attempt to balance so as not to desensitize users so that they ignore the time it occurs on their banking website as just another irritation. In addition (on the more pedantic side), a page with mixed content makes it much easier for a malicious party to track a user as the content sent in the plain can be used to identify the page which they have visited. It also means that the content which is served over http has no level of guarantee that it is unmodified, nor that it is devoid of a potentially malicious additional payload.

Comment: Doesn't HTTPS prevent local caching? I wonder if that would impact imagur's bandwidth [moving to HTTPS.]

Answer (score 1):

The most recent line is "HTTPS isn't supported yet", see comments here: [HTTPS broken (on meta)](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5525/https-broken-on-meta)

Don't go through changing links manually, that will probably make any *official* HTTPS migration harder.